# Error on delete: expression must be a pointer to a complete object type

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to delete a class that is nested within another class inside of an array. I get an intellisense error stating:

> "expression must be a pointer to a complete object type"

I've tried deleting it another way by creating a pointer to the reference of object and Visual Studio errors out and gives me a dll error basically stating the debugging symbols are not loaded.

Here are pieces of the code --

graphl.cpp

```
 GraphL::~GraphL()
{
  NodeData* rmND;   // remove NodeData
  GraphNode* rmGN;  // remove GraphNode

  for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
  {

    deleteEdges(adjList[i]->edgeHead);

    rmGN = adjList[i]; 
    delete rmGN->data;    //////////////// <-- error here
    rmGN->edgeHead = nullptr;
    delete rmGN;
  }

  delete[] adjList;
}
```

graphl.h

```
    class GraphL {

public:
  GraphL();
  ~GraphL();

  void buildGraph(istream& infile);
  void depthFirstSearch();
  //void displayGraph();

private:
  struct EdgeNode {
    int adjGraphNode;
    EdgeNode* nextEdge;
    EdgeNode() : adjGraphNode(0), nextEdge(nullptr) {};
  };
  struct GraphNode {
    EdgeNode* edgeHead;
    NodeData data;
    bool visited;
    GraphNode() : edgeHead(nullptr), visited(false) {};
  };

  static const int MAXNODES = 6;
  GraphNode* adjList[MAXNODES]{}; // adjacency list
  //void makeEmpty();
  int size;
  bool insertEdge(int from, int to);
  void dfsHelper(int search);
  void deleteEdges(EdgeNode* remove);

};
```

nodedata.h

```
class NodeData {
   friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &, const NodeData &);

public:
   NodeData();          // default constructor, data is set to an empty string
   ~NodeData();          
   NodeData(const string &);      // data is set equal to parameter
   NodeData(const NodeData &);    // copy constructor
   NodeData& operator=(const NodeData &);

   // set class data from data file
   // returns true if the data is set, false when bad data, i.e., is eof
   bool setData(istream&);                

   bool operator==(const NodeData &) const;
   bool operator!=(const NodeData &) const;
   bool operator<(const NodeData &) const;
   bool operator>(const NodeData &) const;
   bool operator<=(const NodeData &) const;
   bool operator>=(const NodeData &) const;

private:
   string data;          
};
```

If I tried rmND = rmGN->data; delete rmND; Visual Studio gives me a wntdll.pdb not loaded error. How do I properly delete that object? Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Off-topic, but array indices go from 0 to N-1, not 1 to N.

Comment: 0 is NULL. Its unused and therefore nothing every happens to it. Objects were inserted from 1-N.

Comment: @endanegered -- *0 is NULL. Its unused and therefore nothing every happens to it* -- I've seen too many programs just fail because they try to fake 1-based arrays.  Either that `0` element is used accidentally, or the index goes one-off at the end of the array.  Just start your arrays at `0`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Understood, but not really a choice in this instance. This is an assignment and we're told to start from 1 - N. If a 0 was passed to insert an object at that instance the program ends.

Comment: You're actually learning how to introduce unnecessary bugs in a program.  That `0` index is still valid, and if I had a dollar for every instance I see it being used by mistake in a fake 1-based array program, I would be a rich man.

Comment: Indecies begin at zero. Doesn't matter what your assignment says, it's goal is to get you to understand. Address + (index*sizeof(object)) = memory location. If index=0, then the 'first element' of this memory is being selected. That is how your index will look in lower-level code. Therefore, the last element is N-1. EVEN THOUGH, you have 1->N elements, your index is 0->(N-1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The item you are trying to delete is not a pointer to dynamic memory, it is local to the object and as such, the parent object must be deleted in order for the memory to be cleared.

To be more precise, you can only delete a section of memory which was explicitly created using the new keyword.

It is unnecessary to delete the object.